# xargs with multiple commands

Tags: xargs

I'm trying to execute a sequence of commands on a list of files one by one. I was wondering if it is possible to use xargs something on the lines of

```
ls *.txt | xargs -n 1 -I {} cat {} | grep foo > {}.foo
```

Where

```
cat {} | grep foo > {}.foo
```

is the command I want to execute on each file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might be possible to use something along the lines of

```
xargs -n1 -I[] sh -c 'cat {} | grep foo > {}.foo'
```

or, to get rid of the useless `cat`

```
xargs -n1 -I{} sh -c 'grep foo {} > ().foo'
```

It's usually easier to put it in a shell script so you can just pass it files.

```
cat > fiddle.sh <<\EOF
for f in "$@"; do
  grep foo "$f" >"$f.foo"
done
EOF
ls *.txt | xargs sh fiddle.sh    # note we can now pass multiple files, no -n1 or -I needed
```

Pedantry:  `ls` won't do the right thing with special characters, notably embedded newlines, in filenames.  I'd dump the `xargs` entirely, and (given the above script) just do

```
sh fiddle.sh *.txt
```

or even

```
for f in *.txt; do grep foo "$f" >"$f.txt"; done
```

right at the prompt.